# Techniques for finding repeat transactions between customers with misspellings or other change in information?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, analysis, fuzzy-comparison

This isn't a SQL Server specific question; but there might be tSQL specific options here.

I've got a bunch of customer details; many of them cancel and resign up for their service. They get an entirely new account; and our datavalidation is sketchy at best; so they often mistype email addresses or other data.

The question is in two parts:

First; I've got info such as first and last name, email, last 4 of credit card, postal code, phone number. Is there an algorithm/process I can look at my dataset with and look for common pools of repetition so I can determine some manual characteristics of the data that tend to be 'gotcha' items for repeat customers -- i.e. 80% of the time the emails were 'similar' and the zip code was the same, it was a repeat customer (based upon my human matching skills)?

Second; How might I go about expressing similarity between sets of data --- i.e. have an item called a match if 3 of the 5 fields match? Some sort of similiarity index between all the different data points? I know I can use soundex to some extent on the names... not so sure on email addresses.

So, I'm interested in both quick and dirty solutions (I'm whipping together an analysis tonight; but I'm also very interested in the 'right' ways of going to tackle this problem.) Both answers will earn my love and respect. =)

Answer (score 3):

Not T-SQL, but SSIS has some answers: [Fuzzy Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx), [Fuzzy Grouping Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141764.aspx). This MSDN article shows how to use it: [Fuzzy Lookups and Groupings Provide Powerful Data Cleansing Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163731.aspx), and here is a video on the topic: [MSDN TV: Data Cleansing Applications with SQL Server Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14067).

There are 3rd party solutions too, like Red-Gate's [Data Cleanser](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/data-cleanser/). Still, they use SSIS, as is a much more appropriate tool for the job.

You should also read about [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), there are already many public off-the-shelf T-SQL implementations, as well as CLR ones, usable in SQL Server. Just [Google for them](https://www.google.com/search?q=levenshtein%20distance%20t-sql).

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend looking at the [Jaro-Winkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) fuzzy matching algorithm for querying with, and its CLR implementation can be found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic732037-1345-4.aspx)

This seems to work quite well with smaller volumes of text string matching